# How to create a Kibana (Elasticsearch) Scripted Field programatically?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, nest

Kibana's UI allows the user to create a scripted field which is stored as part of the index (screenshot below).  How can that be done programatically?  In particular, using either the NEST client or the Elasticsearch low level client.

[Kibana UI for the Indice with the Scripted Fields tab highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yqrhd.png)

Note that I am *not* asking how to create add an expression/script field as part of a query, I'm specifically looking for how to add it as part of the Index when the mapping is created so that queries can reference it without having to explicitly include it.

Comment: FYI, from the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/managing-fields.html#create-scripted-field) it seems like the scripted fields cannot be queried.

Answer (score 1):

Kibana dashboards are stored in the .kibana index. To export dashboards, you can query the Kibana index as you would any other index. For example, `curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/.kibana/_search?type=dashboard&pretty` would show the JSON for your dashboards. You could export the template, add the scripted field to the JSON, and then POST it again. Since Kibana uses a standard Elasticsearch index, the normal Elasticsearch API would apply to modifying Kibana dashboards. [This](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/building-kibana-dashboard-dynamically/33713/6) may provide a little more clarification.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, current version 5.2 does not have an official way to do this.

This is how I do it:

1. Get index fields: **GET /.kibana/index-pattern/YOUR_INDEX**
2. Add your scripted field to **_source.fields** (as string, notice scaped quotation marks)

   ```
   "fields":"[...,{\"name\":\"test\",\"type\":\"number\",\"count\":0,\"scripted\":true,\"script\":\"doc['area_id'].value\",\"lang\":\"painless\",\"indexed\":false,\"analyzed\":false,\"doc_values\":false,\"searchable\":true,\"aggregatable\":true}]"
   ```
3. Post back _source json to /.kibana/index-pattern/YOUR_INDEX

   ```
   {
       "title":"YOUR_INDEX",
       "timeFieldName":"time",
       "fields":"[...,{\"name\":\"test\",...}]"
   }
   ```

Comment: This is really too bad. It makes me not use this feature. Suppose I have a fruit business and I want to show numbers of apples and oranges sold per month in a chart. Now I want to add a 'total'. I implemented this using a scripted field and it works PERFECTLY. But since I can't export/import it with the index, I chose now to modify my load script to just calculate it there and add it to a separate field instead.